# Java's Jersey, RESTful API, and JSONP

Tags: java, json, jsonp, jersey

This must have been answered previously, but my Google powers are off today and I have been struggling with this for a bit. We are migrating from an old PHP base to a Jersey-based JVM stack, which will ultimately provide a JSON-based RESTful API that can be consumed from many applications. Things have been really good so far and we love the easy POJO-to-JSON conversion. However, we are dealing with difficulties in Cross-Domain JSON requests. We essentially have all of our responses returning JSON (using @Produces("application/json") and the com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature set to true) but for JSONP support we need to change our methods to return an instance of JSONWithPadding. This of course also requires us to add a @QueryParam("callback") parameter to each method, which will essentially duplicate our efforts, causing two methods to be needed to respond with the same data depending on whether or not there is a callback parameter in the request. Obviously, this is not what we want.

So we essentially have tried a couple different options. Being relatively new to Jersey, I am sure this problem has been solved. I read from a few places that I could write a request filter or I could extend the JSON Provider. My ideal solution is to have no impact on our data or logic layers and instead have some code that says "if there is a call back parameter, surround the JSON with the callback, otherwise just return the JSON". A solution was found here:
http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/JsonP-without-using-JSONWithPadding-td7015082.html

However, that solution extends the Jackson JSON object, not the default JSON provider.

What are the best practices? If I am on the right track, what is class for the default JSON filter that I can extend? Is there any additional configuration needed? Am I completely off track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your resource methods return JSONWithPadding object, then Jersey automatically figures out if it should return JSON (i.e. just the object wrapped by it) or the callback as well based on the requested media type - i.e. if the media type requested by the client is any of application/javascript, application/x-javascript, text/ecmascript, application/ecmascript or text/jscript, then Jersey returns the object wrapped by the callback. If the requested media type is application/json, Jersey returns the JSON object (i.e. does not wrap it with the callback). So, one way to make this work is to make your resource method produce all the above media types (including application/json), always return JSONWithPadding and let Jersey figure out what to do.

If this does not work for you, let us know why it does not cover your use case (at users at jersey.java.net). Anyway, in that case you can use ContainerRequest/ResponseFilters. In the request filter you can modify the request headers any way you want (e.g. adjust the accept header) to ensure it matches the right resource method. Then in the response filter you can wrap the response entity using the JSONWithPadding depending on whether the callback query param is available and adjust the content type header.

Comment: The problem is that jQuery by default sends an Accepts * header, so the requested MIME Type and was sending application/json as the request, even if the type specified was jsonp. I am typing up what I finally got to work in another answer, but in short I wrote a filter and wrapper outside of Jersey to just check for the existence of the callback parameter on a JSON request and, if it exists, add the callback to the response output. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

So what I ultimately ended up doing (before Martin's great response came in) was creating a Filter and a ResponseWrapper that intercepted the output. The basis for the code is at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm

Essentially, the filter checks to see if the callback parameter exists. If it does, it prepends the callback to the outputted JSON and appends the ) at the end. This works great for us in our testing, although it has not been hardened yet. While I would have loved for Jersey to be able to handle it automatically, I could not get it to work with jQuery correctly (probably something on my side, not a problem with Jersey). We have pre-existing jQuery calls and we are changing the URLs to look at the new Jersey Server and we really didn't want to go into each $.ajax call to change any headers or content types in the calls if we didn't have to.

Aside from the small issue, Jersey has been great to work with!